# IBM AS/400 wont compile - RNS9308 Compilation stopped. Severity 30 errors found in program

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, ibm-rad

While working on my final project for my AS/400 Course, I encountered this problem that I can't seem to correct.

[image]

The display file I tried to compile (CHAP12EXP.rpgle) was given to me and I'm not supposed to edit it. From my understanding, I compiled CHAP12DSP and that was successful as well as EMPPFL; those two files can be seen on the left in the screenshot below.

Now this other screenshot is from physical file EMPPF:

[image]

And this final screenshot is from CHAP12DSP.dspf before compiling it. (SCREEN 2)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of the fields `TITLE` and `FIRSTNAME` defined in your display file `CHAP12DSP` does not match the length defined in your physical file `EMPPFL`.

Examine and compare the source DDS for the display file and physical file for the definition of fields `TITLE` and `FIRSTNAME`.

Comment: Thanks James, i did that more carefully this time around and it removed those two warnings but i still have Compilation stopped. Severity 30 errors found. There's one more for me to fix though, SALARY. Hopefully it runs good after that :)